# Relationship between two tables in doctrine. Data dosen't save in database

Tags: doctrine-orm, entities

I have a problem with saving data in Database.I have two tables which are created with Doctrine Entities. My Entities are:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Entities\Cic;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cic_case_files")
 */
class CicCaseFile {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CicCase", inversedBy="cicFiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="case_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $case;

    /**
     * One Product has One Shipment.
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $file;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="case_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $case_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="file_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $file_id;
    public function __construct() {

        //$this->mailboxes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function setFileId($fileId){

        $this->file_id = $fileId;
    }
    public function getFileId(){

        return $this->file_id;
    }
    public function setCaseId($caseId){

        $this->case_id = $caseId;
    }
    public function getCaseId(){

        return $this->case_id;
    }
    public function getId() {

        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getCase(){

        return $this->case;
    }
    public function setCase($case){

        $this->case = $case;
    }
    public function getFile(){

        return $this->file;
    }
    public function setFile($file){

        $this->file = $file;
    }



}



<?php

namespace App\Http\Entities\Cic;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\App\Http\Repositories\Cic\FileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 */
class File
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $originalName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $hashName;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $extension;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getPath(){
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function setPath($path){
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function getOriginalName(){
        return $this->originalName;
    }

    public function setOriginalName($originalName){
        $this->originalName = $originalName;
    }

    public function getHashName(){
        return $this->hashName;
    }

    public function setHashName($hashName){
        $this->hashName = $hashName;
    }

    public function getExtension(){
        return $this->extension;
    }

    public function setExtension($extension){
        $this->extension = $extension;
    }
}
```

My tables:

files:
[image: files table]

cic_case_file:
[image: cic_case_files]

I'd like to save data in table CicCaseFile by code:

```
$cicFile =  new CicCaseFile();
cicFile->setCaseId($caseId);
$cicFile->setFileId($fileId);
$this->entityManager->persist($cicFile);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Something is wrong with my Entities, but I don't know what. Could someone help me with that? I would be very greatful. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to follow if I am in your position.

Your **File** Entity must only have **id, path, extension, original_name, hash_name** properties and methods, you can internally use any conversion methods

Your **CicCaseFile** Entity must only have **id, case_id, file_id**  properties and methods, you can internally use any conversion methods

So what must be your approach while inserting the data is, first you need to insert the data for your parent table ie **file** table then its children table ie **cic_case_file** table

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); /* In Symfony Framework */

$fileObj = new File();
$fileObj->setPath($path);
$fileObj->setExtension($extension);
$fileObj->setOriginalName,($originalName);
$fileObj->setHashName($hashName);
$em->persist($fileObj);
$em->flush(); 

/* So once you flush here it fileObj will be having the last inserted object which you can use to store in child table */

$cicCaseFileObj = new CicCaseFile();
$cicCaseFileObj->setFile($fileObj); /* $fileObj which was inserted above */
$cicCaseFileObj->setCaseId($caseObj); /* Same as $fileObj as inserted above in case if this is from different table */
```

$em->persist($cicCaseFileObj);
$em->flush();

if caseId is inserted in different saveMethod then first you need to fetch the object and then give it to the above object as follows

```
$caseId = 10; /* This you may get from else where */
$caseObj = $em->getRepository('BundleName:Case')->find($caseId);

/* Make sure your case_id is nullable or not */
$cicCaseFileObj = new CicCaseFile();
$cicCaseFileObj->setFile($fileObj);
if($caseObj){
    $cicCaseFileObj->setCaseId($caseObj); 
}
$em->persist($cicCaseFileObj);
$em->flush();
```

Happy Coding!